# How to change iCloud storage size for Emails?

Tags: icloud, email, mobileme

I am using the 25 GB plan for iCloud. This morning I got the message in Mail.app that my iCloud storage is full. However, the iCloud system preferences tell me, I have still 11 GB left. In MobileMe I could set the split on how much would be used for my Email account. How can I increase the Email storage with iCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud mail space should be dynamically increased as you go. There is nothing users can do to manually expand that size. If it is stuck for you, I recommend contacting Apple at their support web page for iCloud, as you are a paying customer, you sure are entitled to great service.